# Is it possible to use tensorflow.js in bixbystudio?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Same as title, is it ever somehow possible to use tensorflow.js in bixbystudio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform custom machine learning for your capsule, it would need to hosted within your own environment that's called via http as a remote endpoint.

One reason, Bixby doesn't support package management like NPM, so you can't pull in the Tensorflow functionality to your 'local' capsule javascript, but it can be called remotely like an API call.

**Bixby does provide some machine learning features natively**.

**[Selection Learning](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/learning.selection-learning)** Allows you to automatically learn from previous selections so that it can personalize the experience and eliminate the need to ask that question every time.  One example is an airline booking.  If you always select a 'aisle' seat, you can have Bixby learn that's the case and not prompt you when it learns that selection preference.

**[Preference Learning](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/learning.preference-learning)** Provides the ability to teach Bixby the user's preferences then use that to highlight it, or sort a list based on a personalized sorting of the most likely choice the user will make.

Comment: thank you for answer & suggestion, also for Bixby native ml features that I didn't know - so much thx